# How to copy a matrix row to an array and modify the array?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm kinda new to Java myself and I was doing some excercises, I find myself stuck in an excersise that asks me to copy the third sequence from a preloaded 4 Row * 20 Column Matrix of characters from a to z, to an array that has the same size (4*20), everytime it copies data from the Matrix it has to be stored from left to right without any wildcard or space on the new array. The excercise gives this code to begin. (The commented methods should be taken as already implented)

```
public class second_excercise {

public static final int MAXROW = 4;

public static final int MAXCOLUMN = 20;

public static final int MAX = MAXROW*MAXCOLUMN;

public static void main(String[] args) {

char [] arrchar;

char [][] matchar;

arrchar = new char[MAX];

matchar = new char[MAXROW][MAXCOLUMN];

//load_array_char(arrchar);

//load_random_char_matrix(matchar);

//Solve the problem in the following method: solve_second_excercise(...)

solve_second_excercise(matchar, arrchar);


}

public static void solve_second_excercise(char [][] matchar, char [] arrchar){

}
```

I have tried some methods myself:

```java
public static char grab_sequence_beginning(char[] arr, char begin){
   while ((begin < MAX)&&(arr[begin]==0))
   begin++;
   return begin;
}


public static char grab_end_sequence(char[] arr, char end){
    while ((end < MAX)&&(arr[end]!=0))
    end++;
    return end-1;
}


      public void add_elements_to_new_array(char [] arrchar, char element){  

           for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
                  {
                      if(array[i] == 0)
           {
              System.arraycopy(array, 0, array, 1, i);
              array[0] = element;
               return;

  }

       public static void print_array(char [] arr){
             for (int pos = 0; pos < MAX; pos++){
            System.out.println("array["+pos+"]=>: "+arr[pos]);
    }  
}
```

Nothing managed to work and I'm kinda lost, the main idea I have is that I need to copy an specific part (the third sequence of chars to be precise) to a new array but I don't really know how to do that, cause the things I tried myself didn't seem to work. I would like some help and indepth explanations are always welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: [How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And please: learn about Java naming conventions. You are violating quite a bit which makes reading your code much harder. Or well, tell your instructor that their input to you is really deficient in that regard.